# Can we have Bose condensation for bosons satisfying a dispersion relation $E=Cp^s$ $\forall$ s?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, quantum-statistics

Suppose a dispersion relation $E=Cp^s$ where $C$ is a constant is known for a collection of massive non-interacting bosons. What is the way to find out whether there will be Bose-Einstein condensation in three-dimensions? In order words, can we have Bose condensation for any value of $s$? What about the dispersion relation $E=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$?

Comment: Of course the relativistic dispersion shows Bose-Einstein condensation. For $T \to 0$ the average momentum goes to zero and then $E \approx mc^2 + p^2/2m$, which is just the classical dispersion relation (for which we know that there is Bose-Einstein condensation in three dimensions). Of course it might get interesting if $mc^2$ gets low enough that even at the condensation temperature the dispersion is non-parabolic. Then there will certainly be corrections to the condensation temperatur.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is we can not. Let $\epsilon(p) = Cp^s$. Bose-Einstein condensation at the temperature $\theta$ in three dimensions is possible if the integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{p^2}{\exp(\epsilon(p)/\theta) - 1}\ dp
$$
is finite. This integral is finite for any $\theta>0$ if $s < 3$. And it is infinite if $s \geq 3$.

Comment: What does that integral in your answer represent? @Gec

Comment: Look here: [Ideal Bose-Einstein gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate#Bose_Einstein's_non-interacting_gas) for a method to find condensation temperature. My integral is just the same.